# Is it possible for a sequence of rational numbers to have a non rational limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I'm solving an exercise, and at some point I have to prove that any inteval $(a,b)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb R$, is  the union of intervals $[\alpha,\beta)$, with $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $\beta \in \mathbb Q$. The values of $\alpha$ are easy to find:

$$(a,b) = \bigcup _{n = k}^{\infty} [a + \frac{1}{n},\text{____})$$

For a value of $k$ sufficiently large such that $a + 1/k \in (a,b)$. But the problem is that I don't know what to put in the place of $\text{_____}$, because we have to put a sequence of rational numbers, but the limit of the sequence has to be the real number $b$. Is it even possible for a sequence of rational numbers to have a limit that is not rational? Because a sequence of real numbers never has a limit that is complex for example, so if $(a_n)_n \in \mathbb Q$ it makes scene that $\lim_n a_n \in \mathbb Q$, but I can be wrong. Is this possible? If so what should be the sequence in _____?

Comment: Sure.  consider the decimal expansion of $\pi$...$\{3,3.1,3.14,3.141,3.1415,\cdots\}$.

Comment: Then what sequence should I put in ______ ? @lulu

Comment: Take the decimal expansion of $b$.

Comment: formally $a_n=\lfloor10^n\pi\rfloor10^{-n}$

Comment: For an arbitrary real number $b$, there is no "nice" formula describing a sequence of rationals that converges to $b$. You need to hack something together using something like the floor function in drhab's example above my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $b_n=10^{-n}\left\lfloor 10^nb\right\rfloor$ will do. You can see that $0\le 10^nb-\lfloor 10^nb\rfloor<1$ by definition, and therefore $0\le b-b_n<10^{-n}$.

You might end up having $[a+1/n, b_n)=\emptyset$ for a while, but it's no biggie. Unless, of course, you are a person who says that $[3,2)=[2,3)$ because he likes $[a,b]$ to denote the segment with endpoints $a$ and $b$. In that case you have to make a caveat of considering only sufficiently large $n$-s.

*Addendum:* The sequence $b_n$ is very similar to the everyday decimal digit expansion.

For positive real numbers it corresponds to the digit expansion rounded below: say, for $b=\sqrt3$ it's $$1,\, 1.7,\, 1.73,\, 1.732,\, 1.732\text{ (again)},\, 1.73205,\, 1.73205\text{ (again)},\, 1.7320508,\cdots$$

For negative real numbers it is the the digit expansion "rounded above" (which would still technically be "below", because the number is negative and larger absolute value corresponds to smaller number): say, for $b=-\sqrt3$ it's $$-2,\, -1.8,\, -1.74,\, -1.733,\, -1.7321,\, -1.73206,\,-1.732051,\,-1.7320509,\cdots$$ and for $b=-1.401$ it's $$-2,\, -1.5,\, -1.41,\, -1.401,\, -1.401,\, -1.401,\,-1.401,\, -1.401,\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $s_{n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n!} \in  \mathbb{Q}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and
$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_{n}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=e\notin \mathbb{Q}$